# How to import bootstarp js in a jasmine test spec file

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a jasmine test spec file and I want include bootstrap js . Kindly let me know , how to add this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Include it in the Jasmine SpecRunner.html file, then run that file in your browser to run the tests.  You can add `bootstrap.js` or anything else you need to run the tests.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Jasmine Spec Runner v2.4.1</title>

  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine_favicon.png">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.css">

  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.4.1/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="lib/jasmine-2.4.1/boot.js"></script>

  <!-- include source files here... -->
  <script src="src/Player.js"></script>
  <script src="src/Song.js"></script>

  <!-- include spec files here... -->
  <script src="spec/SpecHelper.js"></script>
  <script src="spec/PlayerSpec.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```